# Python: how to avoid the space in dna calculated?

Tags: python, sequence, bioinformatics

I am using python 2.7.
I want to find the DNA length. I have no idea where is the mistake.....The length of DNA supposed to be 283, but it comes up with 345.

The sequence in a single line is nothing wrong but just the length have some problem.....

I think the spaces are calculated too. May I know how to get the length of the DNA without including the spaces?

Thank you.

```
import re

singleSeq = ""

fh = open("seq.embl.txt")

lines = fh.readlines()

for line in lines:

    lines = line.strip()

    m = re.match(r"\s+(.[^\d]+)\s+\d+", line)

    if m:
        print(m.group(0))

        seqline = m.group(1)
        print(seqline)

        singleSeq += seqline
    

print("\nSequence in a single line: ")
# print(line.strip(singleSeq))
print(singleSeq)

print("\nSequence length: ", len(singleSeq))
```

Output

Sequence in a single line:
cccatgtccc agcggcgtat tgctttgcat cgcgaacgca ctttcaatgt cccagcggcg    tattgcttct attttataag taccagctaa attttttttt tttttttata agtaccagct    aaaatttttt tttttttttt ttataagtac cagctaaaat tttttttttt tttttttata    agtaccagct aaaatttttt ttttttttta taagttccag cggcgtattg ctttctgaaa    tttaaaaaaa aaaaaaaatt tttttttaat aatatattat ata

Sequence length:  345

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```py
# Python3 code to remove whitespace
def remove(string):
    return string.replace(" ", "")
      
# Driver Program
string = ' t e s t '
print(remove(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are reinventing the wheel her. i strongly suggest you try [BioPython](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) for this

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record = SeqIO.read("seq.embl.txt", "embl")
print("\nSequence length: ", len(record))
```